# difference between starting nodejs application with `yarn start` vs `sudo yarn start`?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, sudo, unzip

I have encountered a very strange bug:

Here is my nodejs function which stream unzips a zip file stored in AWS S3 bucket.
Without actually downloading the entire zip file to local file system, it simply extracts the contents in the zip to local file system.

```
const streamUnzipFromS3ToLocal = async (
  objectBucket: string,
  objectKey: string,
  extractDir: string,
) => {
  try {
    const data = await S3.getFile(objectBucket, objectKey); // data.Body is a readable stream;
    try {
      await pipeline(data.Body, unzipper.Extract({ path: extractDir }));
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error(error);
    }
    logger.info(`${objectKey} is decompressed to ${extractDir}`);
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Failed to stream unzip file ${objectKey}: ${error}`);
    throw new Error('StreamUnzipFromS3Error');
  }
};
```

Here is the `S3.getFile()`:

```
import { s3Client } from 'utils/AWS/s3Client';
import { GetObjectCommand} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

export const getFile = async (bucket_name, object_key) => {
  let res;
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket_name,
    Key: object_key,
  };

  try {
    const data = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(params));
    res = data;
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(`Failed when s3Controller getFile: ${err}`);
  }

  return res;
};
```

After it is completed, I get the hash value of the extracted file. i.e., by running: `md5sum extracted_files/00001.dcm`

Now, I can start the nodejs app with 3 ways:

1. `yarn start`: using this method, the extracted file ends up having a different `md5sum` hash value; I tried 3 times, and got 3 different hash values. And as expected, the when trying to parse the file with `.dcm` tools, it throws an error saying that the file `extracted_files/00001.dcm` is corrupted.
2. `sudo yarn start`;
3. `sudo systemctl start myapp.service`, where `myapp.service` is:

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp backend api 
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/myapp/code/api
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=ubuntu
ExecStart=yarn start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

which is essentially running `yarn start`, with `User=ubuntu`, but with `sudo`.

With method 2 and 3, the extracted file always has the identical hash value, and of course, parsing was successful with `.dcm` tools.

`yarn start` is running this command:

```
nodemon --exec ts-node --files src/index.ts
```

Two questions:

1. what differentiates starting a nodejs application with the above 3 methods, such that method fails but method 2 & 3 works just fine?
2. what is the difference between `sudo yarn start` and `sudo systemctl start myapp.service`?
   The later one is essentially running `yarn start`, with `User=ubuntu`, but with `sudo`?

---

---

```
ubuntu@ip-123-123-123-123:~/myapp/api$ sudo which node
/usr/bin/node
ubuntu@ip-123-123-123-123:~/myapp/api$ sudo node -v
v10.19.0

ubuntu@ip-123-123-123-123:~/myapp/api$ which node
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.2.0/bin/node
ubuntu@ip-123-123-123-123:~/myapp/api$ node -v 
v21.2.0

ubuntu@ip-123-123-123-123:~/myapp/api$ yarn -v 
1.22.19
ubuntu@ip-123-123-123-123:~/myapp/api$ which yarn 
/usr/bin/yarn
ubuntu@ip-123-123-123-123:~/myapp/api$
```

Comment: can you please show the output `which yarn` and `yarn version`

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi  Thank you for your response; I have updated with the versions information;

Comment: What is `yarn start` doing, ie what's the `start` script in your *package.json*?

Comment: @Bergi  Sorry I missed this important info:  `yarn start` is doing: `nodemon --exec ts-node --files src/index.ts`